# Проблема с TimeZone при коннекте через postgres_fdw

Tags: postgresql

На двух базах, что на разных серверах, настроена таймзона на Москву, в
этом сомнений нет.

С первой базы нужно провести вставку во внешнюю таблицу, которая
создана на второй базе.

На этой таблице во второй базе стоит триггер, который проверяет по
приходящей в одном из полей дате создания, в какую секцию следует
вставить запись.

Даты с первой базы уходят в московском поясе, а в триггере от даты
почему-то отнимается 3 часа.
Т.е., пояс не только превращается в +00, но кол-во часов в дате
уменьшается на кол-во часов в поясе.

Вопрос: как указать postgres_fdw, чтобы в сессии он использовал
московский пояс, а не UTC? Временный костыль - в триггере
устанавливать пояс насильно, это решает, но так не хотелось бы делать.

В его коде нашел это ( configure_remote_session() ) :

```
/* Force the search path to contain only pg_catalog (see deparse.c) */
372  do_sql_command(conn, "SET search_path = pg_catalog");
373
374  /*
375  * Set remote timezone; this is basically just cosmetic, since all
376  * transmitted and returned timestamptzs should specify a zone explicitly
377  * anyway. However it makes the regression test outputs more predictable.
378  *
379  * We don't risk setting remote zone equal to ours, since the remote
380  * server might use a different timezone database. Instead, use UTC
381  * (quoted, because very old servers are picky about case).
382  */
383  do_sql_command(conn, "SET timezone = 'UTC'");
```